# Notes and guidelines to follow to support IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

Are there any good notes and guidelines that one should think about when developing sites that must support Internet Explorer 6?

I'm not looking for explanations of the abundance of bugs that we have all learned by now. I need some general informations on, e.g., elements that one should prefer for certain tasks, things that simply does not work in IE6, CSS tips, etc.

Comment: STOP SUPPORTING IE6!

Comment: @Kyle: I agree, and I even upvoted your comment, but some people don't have that luxury. For example, OP could be doing work targeting corporations which are stuck on IE6 due to dependence on applications that won't run on anything else. Sad, but true.

Comment: http://www.ie6nomore.com/ is a good resource for that ;)

Comment: @Kyle: As AgentConundrum is saying, not everyone has that luxury. At the moment, I'm in the clear, but it's better to be prepared for situations where you actually do have to support it.

Comment: I Agree with you both, sometimes a company still uses it, I've been in that situation and am happy (an proud) to say I managed to get them to switch to newer browsers, but I do know it's mostly impossible to do that!

Answer (score 3):

here are the biggies i can think of right now:

- No Alpha Transparent PNG Support
- No Hover States except for the `<a >` tag
- CSS floats behaving unexpectedly.
- Can't use max/min width/height.
- The Box-model conflict (padding is not added to the width of elements).
- sometimes doubles margins.
- IE6 doesn't support position: fixed.

...and i'm starting to get depressed so i'll stop here.

Comment: Those are all good tips, but they are all simply CSS shortcomings or bugs of some sort. What I would like to know are more specific scenarios, e.g., if I'm to make a vertical menu on the right side of the body of a page, what is the best way to markup that when supporting IE6? Things like that.

Comment: there are about a gazillion to the 64th power of such scenarios. most involving at least one of the six base problems i outlined.

Comment: or to put it another way: 'when making a vertical menu on the right side of the body of a page, it is always a good idea to rememeber that you should not use transparent pngs, and that hover states only apply to '<a>' elements, and that floats will behave unexpectedly, and that the box model behaves differently, that padding will be interpreted idfferently, that your right margin might be unexplicably doubled, and that IE6 does not support position: fixed.'  you mean something more like that?

Comment: @Deniz: there are only two reasons to use different markup and/or CSS for any task in IE 6. 1. A bit of HTML/CSS isn’t supported in IE 6. 2. A bit of HTML/CSS has a bug in IE 6. So that’s actually the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fortunate in that I don't have to support IE6 any more. However it is a recent memory, so you have my sympathies.

1. Go to [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html). This is an excellent resource for finding out what features various browsers support. (seeing all the red in the IE6 column will depress you though!)
2. If you plan to do any scripting at all, use jQuery rather than trying to work with plain Javascript: jQuery makes considerable efforts to be cross-browser compatible, even in IE6. It isn't 100%, but it makes a pretty good go at it, and give you features that would otherwise be completely impossible in IE6.
3. The following tools will make your life easier:

   - [Dean Edwards' ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) - a JS library aimed at making IE6 more compatible with standards (he's also written "ie8.js" and "ie9.js" which extend the original ie7.js to add more features missing in various versions of IE)
   - [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) - a JS/CSS library aimed at helping you work around incompatibilities in old browsers.
   - [IEPNGHack](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) - allows you to use PNG graphics with transparency in IE6.
   - [Whatever:Hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html) - allows you to use the `:hover` CSS style with any element type (IE6 normally only allows `:hover` for `<a>` tags).
   - [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie) - a library aimed at giving IE6/7/8 some modern CSS3 features, including border radius.

There's probably more, but that should give you a start.

One thing to make clear to your employer though is that as long as they insist on using or supporting IE6, you will be unable to produce a modern feature-rich web site. There are limits to how good you'll be able to make it, even with all those hacks. Plus it'll be slow: IE6 is painfully slow at the best of times, and all those hacks will only make it slower.

Best of luck.

Comment: +1; some excellent info, more directed toward concrete solutions than my answer was!

Answer (score 1):

While simply saying "Don't Support IE6!" might sound real nice and easy to those who do not have to deal with reality, it remains a fact that many web developers/designers simply have *no control whatsoever* over that decision.

With that said, obviously the ideal would be "don't support ie6".

If you must support it, how much you have to support it depends on why you must; Is it because your web app is for a company which has many IE6 installations that it knows it won't be upgrading any time soon at all, or is it just for a client who wants to maintain 'support' for every possible user out there? Or is it something in between?

Generally speaking, I aim for "functional, non-totally-ugly, but certainly not pixel-perfect" appearance on IE6. I use IETester to check all versions of IE (differences abound between IE7 and IE8, for instance), so I include IE6 too, and just worry about making things look mostly functional for them.

For my clients, that has been sufficient. A couple have asked about IE6 support, and I have been able to show them that 1) the set of general users on the Internet who still use it is *relatively* small and 2) those users probably see so many glitches everywhere on the web anyway, they probably do not notice them anymore. I know that #2 probably sounds extremely dismissive, but I have plenty of anecdotal evidence that backs it up.

The basic idea comes down to; how much time will you really spend tweaking a site to make it perfect for an old, long-since-unsupported browser which use keeps going down more each day, when you could just make it acceptably functional, and then devote the rest of your time to more modern browsers.

But again, the extent to which you can take that route depends on how important IE6 support is to those who employ you, and why it is that important to them.

but anyway, IETester is a definite recommendation for testing it: 
http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 1):

Poor you having to support IE6, we've all been there I guess...

Unfortunately I cannot point you to some general guidelines, besides the KISS principle (keep it simple stupid). Just stick to CSS 2.1 and don't use any fancy new technologies such as HTML5. Also don't even think of using any kind of special CSS selectors like `blabla > blabla`.

Let me point you to some sites which might help you in your endeavor:

- [CSS contents and browser compability](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) (good overview of what to do and not to do with CSS)
- [ie6fixer](http://www.onderhond.com/tools/ie6fixer/) (you actually WANT to use opacity, transparent png's? this tool will help you)
- [universal-ie6-css](http://code.google.com/p/universal-ie6-css/) (good starting point for your custom css)
- [Ultimate IE6 Cheatsheet: How To Fix 25+ Internet Explorer 6 Bugs](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/tutorials/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs) (fixing the shortcomings the manual way)

For testing I recommend setting up a small virtual machine (I'd suggest using windows xp) with IE6 running. Testing tools like IETester may use the engine of the particular browser, but I have had differences between a full blown IE6 and the IETester tools - <strike>oh also there is instant virtualization with Spoon.net browser sandboxes</strike> (they had to remove IE, because MS said so...).

Comment: +1 for linking to Quirksmode.org - simply the best resource available for checking browser compatibility with various features. (if you read the charts there you'll see lots and lots of stuff that IE6 doesn't support; you will get depressed)